# how to serialize string to xml with serilog or nlogger

Tags: c#, xml, format

i want to format string to xml with c#, i'am using dotnet 7, from my principal method i receive a xml string and i do my internal job and return also a xml string.
my issue is i want to log the xml request and the xml response from my log with serilog.
bellow are two methodes i use to format the string to xml.

```
public static string Serialize<T>(this T value)
    {
        string ret = string.Empty;
        if (value is not null)
        {
            //Create xmlSerializer
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            //write to the string
            using(var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(sw, value);
                ret = sw.ToString();
            }
        }

        return ret;

    }
```

and

```
public static string PrintXML(string xml)
    {
        string result = "";

        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(mStream, Encoding.Unicode);
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

        try
        {
            // Load the XmlDocument with the XML.
            document.LoadXml(xml);

            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

            // Write the XML into a formatting XmlTextWriter
            document.WriteContentTo(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            mStream.Flush();

            // Have to rewind the MemoryStream in order to read
            // its contents.
            mStream.Position = 0;

            // Read MemoryStream contents into a StreamReader.
            StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(mStream);

            // Extract the text from the StreamReader.
            string formattedXml = sReader.ReadToEnd();

            result = formattedXml;
        }
        catch (XmlException)
        {
            // Handle the exception
        }

        mStream.Close();
        writer.Close();

        return result;
    }
}
```

but both of them is not giving me what i need, from the log the entire xml string is on one single line and i want the xml to be format so each tag in one line.

bellow is my principal method where i receive the xml request string:

```
 public  String ProcessVerificationRequest(String requestXmlString)
    {
        //var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
        //xml.Indent = true;
        TextReader text_xml = new StringReader(requestXmlString);
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(text_xml);
        _log.LogInformation($"verification request xml :  {XmlSerializationHelper.PrintXML(requestXmlString)}");
        XDocument response_document = readxml_file();
```

but from my log file its not well formated.

and this my log result:

```
verification request xml :  <FPEnvelope xmlns=\"urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:verification_request\" xmlns:document=\"urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.023.001.03\" xmlns:header=\"urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.03\">\r\n  <header:AppHdr>\r\n    <header:Fr>\r\n      <header:FIId>\r\n        <header:FinInstnId>\r\n          <header:Othr>\r\n            <header:Id>10000091</header:Id>\r\n          </header:Othr>\r\n        </header:FinInstnId>\r\n      </header:FIId>\r\n    </header:Fr>\r\n    <header:To>\r\n      <header:FIId>\r\n        <header:FinInstnId>\r\n          <header:Othr>\r\n            <header:Id>FP</header:Id>\r\n
```

Please can someone Assist me ?

Answer (score -1):

Not all your tags are closed.  Here is proper xml

```
<FPEnvelope xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:verification_request" xmlns:document="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.023.001.03" xmlns:header="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.03">
    <header:AppHdr>
        <header:Fr>
            <header:FIId>
                <header:FinInstnId>
                    <header:Othr>
                        <header:Id>10000091</header:Id>
                    </header:Othr>
                </header:FinInstnId>
            </header:FIId>
        </header:Fr>
        <header:To>
            <header:FIId>
                <header:FinInstnId>
                    <header:Othr>
                        <header:Id>FP</header:Id>
                    </header:Othr>
                </header:FinInstnId>
            </header:FIId>
        </header:To>
    </header:AppHdr>
</FPEnvelope>
```

To parse a string use following

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @jdweng but im receiving the request its not saved in a file,the xml string is a request coming from outside of the app

Comment: That is why is read first into a string.  All you need to do is use the Parse method with your string.